# moviepy libunwind: pc not in table, pc=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: python, moviepy, libunwind

Inside msys mingw 64 I run this:

```
Χρήστος@Chris-pc MINGW64 /c/Python/Scripts/Papinhio player/src/main/python_files
$ python
Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:54:59)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import moviepy.editor
libunwind:      pc not in table, pc=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>>>
```

The module works correct with no problems, but what `libunwind:      pc not in table, pc=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this line:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
```

with this line

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
```

And the warning hide.